# GROUP BY clause in JPQL

Tags: hibernate, jpa, group-by, jpql, oracle-xe

I use Hibernate as persistence provider, database is Oracle XE.
Here is a JP QL query:

```
SELECT news, COUNT(comments) 
  FROM News news JOIN news.comments comments 
GROUP BY news
```

`News` is in one-to-many relation with `Comments`.

When i try to use it, the following error appears:

```
ERROR SqlExceptionHelper:146 - ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
```

But in **Pro JPA 2, 2nd edition** (page 222) I found almost the same query:

```
SELECT e, COUNT(p)
FROM Employee e JOIN e.phones p
GROUP BY e
```

What's wrong with the former one?

Comment: Perhaps `employee.e` is a valid field.

Comment: But `e` is an identification variable for `Employee`.

Comment: I'm just pointing out that Oracle would not complain about that query if `e` were also a column in the table.

Comment: Try to add the sql query that generates Hibernate for this query to see where is the problem. Perhaps it is case sensitive issue on the identification variables. For print out the queries you can set the Hibernate's property show_sql to true (ser in the persistent.xml)

Comment: It's not good to have a column "news" with the same name as the table "news".